# using php to find if a array value exist in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have this array called $top, It consist of vehicle models like so -

```
$top = array('tacoma', 'corolla', 'camry');
```

I would like to know if any of these values exist in a for loop var called $title, im using this to get an rss feed. I have tried using array_search with no luck like so -

```
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $c++;
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);

}


for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = $feed[$x]['title'];
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $item = $feed[$x]['item'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    $desc = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $description);
    $title = strtolower($title);

    $find= array_search($top, $title);

    if ($find) {
        // insert all matches in database
    } else {
        echo 'nothing found';
    }

}
```

Here is an example of what $title produces - toyota corolla ce low miles (chico) $4500. I would like to identify if corolla exist in the title using the array $top.

Here is what I get when I echo $title -

2012 chevy camaro 45th anniversary edition (chico/orland) $115002006 mitsubishi raider dura-cross pick-up for sale (yuba city, ca.) $59002016 dodge ram 2500 (corning) $430002016 dodge ram 2500 (corning) $4300020062007 toyota corolla ce low miles (chico) $4500 etc... So what I would like is to pull all titles that contain one of the strings in the $top array.

Comment: did you apllied this `if-else` inside `for` loop? I am unable to see. Also `$top = array(tacoma, corolla, camry);` is invalid, it need to be `$top = array('tacoma', 'corolla', 'camry');`. Also we don't know what is `$feed`? can you show it's values?

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated with more info..Yes the if-else is inside the for loop

Comment: `Yes the if-else is inside the for loop `? where? add it properly. not as separate logic

Comment: did you try `array_key_exists()`. for more info https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change tour code like below (changes given in comment):-

```
<?php
$feed = [];//create an empty array variable
$top = array('tacoma', 'corolla', 'camry'); // predefine array
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    //$c++; not needed because no where used
    $feed[] = [ 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        ]; // assign value directly
}

foreach($feed  as $fee){ //use foreach it will take care of indexes
    $title = $fee['title'];
    $link = $fee['link'];
    $description = $fee['desc'];
    $item = $fee['item'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($fee['date']));
    $desc = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $description);
    $title = strtolower($title);

    $find= array_search($top, $title);

    if (count(array_intersect($top, explode(" ",$title)))>0) { 
        echo $title. " matched";
    } else {
        echo 'nothing found';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get "nothing found" looped about 20 times but no matches

Comment: @RyanD  show me the  different value of `$title`.`echo` it and show me what you get

Comment: Ok I added it to the question

Comment: @RyanD  check my answer now . I have edited `if-else` condition part.Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) and [`count`](http://php.net/count):

```
if (count(array_intersect($top, $title)) > 0) {
    // do something
} else {
    echo 'nothing found';
}
```

---

**Explanation:**
When the intersection of two arrays leaves one or more values, then it is present, otherwise it is not.

---

**Note:** Make sure that you are over-writing `$title` every time inside the for loop. If you use `if` outside the `for`, only last value holds!

Comment: Thanks, it only produces a value when nothing is found. Doesn't show there were any intersects